# How to get National Geographic basemap in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, data

I'm proficient in ESRI's products and recently started using QGIS.

I've used the national geographic world map (**[NatGeo_World_Map](http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services)**) in ArcMap, but am struggling to replicate this in QGIS. The map is also available **[here](http://geocommons.com/maps/142374)**.

Comment: You need to find wms link for the base map and then follow this tutorial http://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgiswms